Waydroid can't found android_id
I want to install Waydroid. I installed Waydroid successfully, but when I type this command sudo waydroid shell and this command ANDROID_RUNTIME_ROOT=/apex/com.android.runtime ANDROID_DATA=/data ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT=/apex/ com.android.tzdata ANDROID_I18N_ROOT=/apex/com.android.i18n sqlite3 /data/data/ com.google.android.gsf/databases/gservices.db "select * from main where name = \"android_id\" ; " It will appear like this /system/bin/sh: com.android.tzdata: inaccessible or not found. I don't know how to solve this.
OS: Ubuntu 24.04


Looks like there's a space between /apex/ and com.android.tzdata, and also /data/data/ and com.google.android.gsf/databases/gservices.db. Not sure if that's a typo when copy-pasting, or if that's the exact command you ran.

You have a typo error, the correct command should be:
ANDROID_RUNTIME_ROOT=/apex/com.android.runtime \
ANDROID_DATA=/data \
ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT=/apex/com.android.tzdata \
ANDROID_I18N_ROOT=/apex/com.android.i18n \
sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.gsf/databases/gservices.db \
"select * from main where name = \"android_id\" ;"

or in one line:
ANDROID_RUNTIME_ROOT=/apex/com.android.runtime ANDROID_DATA=/data ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT=/apex/com.android.tzdata ANDROID_I18N_ROOT=/apex/com.android.i18n sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.gsf/databases/gservices.db "select * from main where name = \"android_id\" ;"

